# Declaring a multi dimensional dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to make a two dimensional dictionary in python. e.g. `new_dic[1][2] = 5`

When I make `new_dic = {}`, and try to insert values, I get a `KeyError`:

```
new_dic[1][2] = 5
KeyError: 1
```

How to do this?

Comment: There is no accepted answer and I think the author was expecting a nice solution that keeps some properties of multidimensional arrays, but in a sparse setting. Like easy looping on the elements of a row or a column. With nested dictionaries, you can easily select a "row" as an inner dict and then iterate over the inner dict. But it is not symetric, if you want to select a "column" and iterate over the corresponding cells, the code does not look similar at all.

Comment: I think a data structure that handles this with a multidimensional get() would really be nice. get([1, 1, None, None, 2]) on a "5-dimensional dict" would return a "slice", a "2-dimensional dict" of it where the values of dimension 1 and 2 are 1, of dimension 5 is 2, and the values of dimensions 3 and 4 are free. get() should either return a cell if 0-dimensional "slice" or an iterator in most cases or a duplicated sub-multi-dict.

Answer (score 93):

A multi-dimensional dictionary is simply a dictionary where the values are themselves also dictionaries, creating a nested structure:

```
new_dic = {}
new_dic[1] = {}
new_dic[1][2] = 5
```

You'd have to detect that you already created `new_dic[1]` each time, though, to not accidentally wipe that nested object for additional keys under `new_dic[1]`.

You can simplify creating nested dictionaries using various techniques; using [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) for example:

```
new_dic.setdefault(1, {})[2] = 5
```

`dict.setdefault()` will only set a key to a default value if the key is still missing, saving you from having to test this each time.

Simpler still is using the [`collections.defaultdict()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create nested dictionaries automatically:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_dic = defaultdict(dict)
new_dic[1][2] = 5
```

`defaultdict` is just a subclass of the standard `dict` type here; every time you try and access a key that doesn't yet exist in the mapping, a factory function is called to create a new value. Here that's the [`dict()` callable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), which produces an empty dictionary when called.

Demo:

```
>>> new_dic_plain = {}
>>> new_dic_plain[1] = {}
>>> new_dic_plain[1][2] = 5
>>> new_dic_plain
{1: {2: 5}}
>>> new_dic_setdefault = {}
>>> new_dic_setdefault.setdefault(1, {})[2] = 5
>>> new_dic_setdefault
{1: {2: 5}}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> new_dic_defaultdict = defaultdict(dict)
>>> new_dic_defaultdict[1][2] = 5
>>> new_dic_defaultdict
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {1: {2: 5}})
```

Answer (score 37):

Check it out:

```
def nested_dict(n, type):
    if n == 1:
        return defaultdict(type)
    else:
        return defaultdict(lambda: nested_dict(n-1, type))
```

And then:

```
new_dict = nested_dict(2, float)
```

Now you can:

```
new_dict['key1']['key2'] += 5
```

You can create as many dimensions as you want, having the target type of your choice:

```
new_dict = nested_dict(3, list)
new_dict['a']['b']['c'].append(5)
```

Result will be:

```
new_dict['a']['b']['c'] = [5]
```

Comment: Trying to use this (which is awesome by the way). But need to remove a 2nd level item like "del new_dict['key1']['key2]" but all I get is an object is not subscriptable.

Comment: I think this one should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

One simple way is to just use tuples as keys to a regular dictionary. So your example becomes this:

`new_dic[(1, 2)] = 5`

The downside is that all usages have to be with this slightly awkward convention, but if that's OK, this is all you need.

Comment: This is perfect for what I need: `new_dic[("orange", "apple", "coconut")] = {"": ""}`

Comment: Good answer. Note that you don't need the parentheses, `new_dic[1,2] = 5` will also use the tuple `(1,2)` as key.

Answer (score 11):

Simply, you can use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_dic = defaultdict(dict)
new_dic[1][2]=5
>>>new_dic
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {1: {2: 5}})
```

Answer (score 6):

u can try this, it is even easier if it is string

```
new_dic = {}
a = 1
new_dic[a] = {}
b = 2
new_dic[a][b] = {}
c = 5
new_dic[a][b]={c}
```

type

```
new_dic[a][b]
>>>'5'
```

For string

```
new_dic = {}
a = "cat"
new_dic[a] = {}
b = "dog"
new_dic[a][b] = {}
c = 5
new_dic[a][b] = {c}
```

type

```
new_dic["cat"]["dog"]
>>>'5'
```

Comment: Dsw: did a great job here. I was looking for such a solution. I can build a structure based on this acting like a multi-dimensional dictionary and put the values on the second plan.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `dict` or `list`?

And if you mean `dict` do you want the second level to be another `dict`? or a `list`?

For a `dict` to work you need to have declared the keys ahead of time.

So if it's `dicts` in `dicts` you need something like this:

```
new_dic = {}
try:
    new_dic[1][2] = 5
except KeyError:
    new_dic[1] = {2:5}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dictionary that contains another dictionary as the value for key 1:

```
>>> new_dic = {}
>>> new_dic[1] = {2:5}
>>> new_dic
{1: {2: 5}}
```

The problem that you had with

```
new_dic={}
new_dic[1][2]=5
```

is that `new_dic[1]` does not exist, so you can't add a dictionary (or anything for that matter) to it.

Answer (score -2):

For project, I needed to have 2D dict of class instances, where indeces are float numbers (coordinates). What I did, was to create 2D dict using default dict, and pass my class name as a type. For ex.:

```
class myCoordinates:
    def __init__(self, args)
    self.x = args[0]
    self.y = args[1]
```

and then when I tried to create dictionary:

```
table = mult_dim_dict(2, myCoordinates, (30, 30))
```

where function 'mult_dim_dict' defined as:

```
def mult_dim_dict(dim, dict_type, params):
    if dim == 1:
        if params is not None:
            return defaultdict(lambda: dict_type(params))
        else: 
            return defaultdict(dict_type)
    else:
        return defaultdict(lambda: mult_dim_dict(dim - 1, dict_type, params))
```

Note: you cannot pass multiple arguments, instead you can pass a tuple, containing all of your arguments. If your class, upon creation, does not need any variables to be passed, 3rd argument of function will be `None`:

```
class myCoors:
def __init__(self, tuple=(0, 0)):
    self.x, self.y = tuple

def printCoors(self):
    print("x = %d, y = %d" %(self.x, self.y))


def mult_dim_dict(dim, dict_type, params):
    if dim == 1:
        if params is not None:
            return defaultdict(lambda: dict_type(params))
        else:
            return defaultdict(dict_type)
    else:
        return defaultdict(lambda: mult_dim_dict(dim - 1, dict_type, params))

dict = mult_dim_dict(2, myCoors, None)
dict['3']['2'].x = 3
dict['3']['2'].y = 2

dict['3']['2'].printCoors()  # x = 3, y = 2 will be printed

dict = mult_dim_dict(2, myCoors, (30, 20))
dict['3']['2'].printCoors()  # x = 30, y = 20 will be printed
```