# Nested dictionary with defaults

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, defaultdict

Is there a way to make a nested dictionary such that I can say `mydict[x][y][z] += 1`, where `mydict[x][y][z]` did not previously exist, and defaults to 0 (and would be 1 after incrementing)?

I looked into answers to a similar question in which you can say `mydict[x][y][z] = 1` using `defaultdict` from the `collections` class ([Declaring a multi dimensional dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348345/declaring-a-multi-dimensional-dictionary-in-python)), but this does not allow you to assume a default value and then increment.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you're doing, you might also be able to do a single `defaultdict` (or `Counter`) with tuple keys: `mydict = defaultdict(int); mydict[(x, y, z)] += 1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: Counter()))

d['A']['B']['C'] += 1

# defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#             {'A': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>.<locals>.<lambda>>,
#                          {'B': Counter({'C': 1})})})
```

Note this is also possible via only using nested `defaultdict`:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))
```

However, given `Counter` was created for the specific purpose of incrementing integers, this would be the method I prefer.