# Nested defaultdict raises AttributeError

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am using a nested defaultdict to keep code clean and reduce the redundant code.

I am constructing a dictionary such as:

```py
{"Store1": {"Product1": 1}, "Store2": {"Product1": 2, "Product2": 1}}
```

I tried to implement the answer to this question [Nested dictionary with defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672708/nested-dictionary-with-defaults), which would raise the exception:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: Counter()))
d["Store1"]["Product1"] += 1
print(d)
```

is there anyway I can for example:

```
d["Store1"]["Product1"] += 1
```

Comment: What about `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))`?

Comment: This works! :). Could you you please explain why it works? I could also mark your comment as a solution if you add it as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the following

```py
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: Counter()))
d["Store1"]["Product1"] += 1
```

then, `d["Store1"]` will create a new element of "type" `defaultdict(lambda: Counter())` and thus `d["Store1"]["Product1"]` will create a new element of type `Counter`. Hence when you do `+= 1`, it attempts to augment the `Counter` object by `1`. This, however, is not defined, as the types are not compatible:

```py
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/---/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 832, in __iadd__
    for elem, count in other.items():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

As you can observe, it assumes that the right hand side follows the `Mapping` protocol and it attempts to add the r.h.s. counts to its own. I.e. something like:

```py
>>> c = Counter(a=1)
>>> c += Counter(a=2, b=3)
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 3})
```

When you use `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))` on the other hand, then `d["Store1"]["Product1"]` creates a new `int` object, which can be incremented by `+= 1` and written back to the dict.

Comment: Thank you for both the answer and explanation! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like that

```py
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: Counter()))
d["A"]["B"]["Store1"] += 1
print(d)
```